# How to change to the hand cursor with GLUT (in windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, cursor, glut

I'm using GLUT in a C++ OpenGL project.
I tried to use the glutSetCursor function in order to get the common 'hand' cursor, which usually appears in other applications when hovering something clickable.
However, none of the GLUT_CURSOR defines gives me that cursor.
One of the defines is GLUT_CURSOR_INFO with the description 'Pointing hand', which I would assume is what I want, however this only gives me the SizeAll cursor (probably as a fallback).

Is there something else I need to do to get this cursor to work, or is this a problem with GLUT in Windows?

(I'm currently using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GLUT is a very simplicistic framework and you just hit one of it's limits. Time to look for another framework to use.

Comment: Would you recommend freeglut instead, or something different altogether?

Comment: @Fluffy: FreeGLUT suffers from the same problem. I'm thought something in the direction of Qt; yes I know this is no longer lightweight, but it gives you way more control over things like this.

Comment: Freeglut has never come up short for me, glutSetCursor: https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node28.html

Comment: @Charlie: `GLUT_CURSOR_INFO`is not always a hand. May as well be an arrow with a question mark on it.

Comment: What about making your own cursor? glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE); and then just using your own graphics. Its not like your doing winapi ;) speaking of, I bet you could use winapi and modify the cursor that way

Comment: @Charlie: If you draw "your own" cursor using OpenGL it's not going to be a hardware overlay and suffer from input→display render chain latencies. The cursor you normally see on your screen and set using the proper graphics system APIs is in fact a small overlay sprite supported by the GPU which position can be updated rapidly and immediately reflects on image scanout to the display. Also drawing a cursor using OpenGL suffers from the small inconvenience, that it's ultimately clipped by the window viewport borders and can't "reach outside" of the window.

Comment: The only real option I see, is to use winapi to "style" the mouse, but you lose some control over it in the process. That being said; there should be a way to access the hinstance of the process, and use winapi for lower system-access to the mouse/icon, but only for windows systems. 

I think a minimal amount of latency could be a fair trade for more direct control of it, appearence, shape, size, onscreen-functionality etc.